# WARNING vsh: [bus.cc(638)] Bus::SendWithReplyAndBlock took 30029ms to process

Tags: linux, terminal, debian

I run Linux Debian/Ubuntu on my Chromebook. Sometimes when I try to open the terminal, I get this error:
`WARNING vsh: [bus.cc(638)] Bus::SendWithReplyAndBlock took 30029ms to process message: type=method_call, path=/org/chromium/VmCicerone, interface=org.chromium.VmCicerone, member=LaunchVshd ERROR vsh: [object_proxy.cc(621)] Failed to call method: org.chromium.VmCicerone.LaunchVshd: object_path= /org/chromium/VmCicerone: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken. ERROR vsh: [vsh.cc(137)] Failed to send dbus message to cicerone service`

Can anyone help me get rid of this?